# About error class

Tags: c++

which header file should I include in order to use error();

Moreover, I could not use std_lib_facilities.h.
It says no such file.

Answer (score 2):

std_lib_facilities.h is an example library for the book Programming principles and practices using C++. You can get it from here: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h

**Make sure to save as text**, for more information check out your book, there is mention of it pages 1153-1154 as well as in some earlier chapter that I can't seem to find at this moment.

error() is just a function (really a group of them) from this header file, it is not part of the C++ standard library.

To include the header you must download it from above, put it in the same file, and add the following line to the top of your code (or make sure its correct if it is there)

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
```

He also has a page listing other resources that you can find here http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're reading [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321543726) by **Bjarne Stroustrup**. If so, then he has written a `std_lib_facilities.h`  for his examples in his book. It has all the common headerfiles, programmers usually include in their program.

I'm sure he has mentioned somewhere in the beginning what does this file contain. Search for that. Once you find that, create a header file with same name and include all those header files which Bjarne has mentioned in his file!

Here is what I got from his site : http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h

He has special site for this book where you can find many useful information:

http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/